# How can I get class member names and values without using vars() or __dict___

Tags: python, class, reflection

When my class doesn't override `__slots__`, I can get the names and values of all the members of an instance of the class. For example:

```
class Animal(object):
    #__slots__ = ('legs','name','color','smell','age','kids')
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 2
        self.name = 'Dog'
        self.color= 'Spotted'
        self.smell= 'Alot'
        self.age  = 10
        self.kids = 0

a = Animal()

for x in vars(a).items():
    print(x[0],x[1])
```

And the output is

```
age 10
legs 2
name Dog
kids 0
smell Alot
color Spotted
```

However, if I uncomment the `__slots__ = ...` line in the code above and run it, I will get an error that says `vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`.

Is there anyway I can get the names and values of all the members when `__slots__` is overridden?

Comment: Use `__slots__`?

Comment: @kindall. Thanks. I can get the names by using `__slots__`. How can I get  the values?

Comment: You could use a dictionary comprehension: `{k: getattr(obj, k) for k in obj.__slots__}` for example (where `obj` is the object).

Comment: @kindall. Thanks. That's the same solution as in lpozo's post. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Animal(object):
    __slots__ = ('legs','name','color','smell','age','kids')
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 2
        self.name = 'Dog'
        self.color= 'Spotted'
        self.smell= 'Alot'
        self.age  = 10
        self.kids = 0

a = Animal()

for var in a.__slots__:
    print(var + '=' + str(getattr(a, var)))
```